# How to write Structured Stream to S3?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-structured-streaming

I have been searching how to write structured stream results to s3 but could not find a way to do it. I tried several options but each resulted with a different error. Here is what I want to do:

- Read a csv stream
- Reduce it to 2-3 lines of results containing average values in a group. Like this:

  ```
  groupA, 15000
  groupB, 10000
  ```
- Then write these results to a s3 bucket in a single file, possibly overwrite as new input streams come.​ So I tried doing this way:

  ```
  query.writeStream
  .format("text")
  .option("path", s3n://...")
  .outputMode("complete")
  ...
  ```

But it didn't work, spark complained that text format cannot be in complete output mode. But isn't the complete mode the only option that can give me the results I want? I also tried with append mode but then spark complained that I had aggregations and that I should have watermark. But isn't watermark irrelevant to my problem because I dont have timestamps in my csv?​